# Can I retrieve an expired cache entry from an Infinispan server listener using @ClientCacheEntryExpired?

Tags: infinispan, cache-expiration, hot-rod

I am modifying an embedded Infinispan application to use the Infinispan server and HotRod client.  The embedded implementation relied on detecting cache expiration events in a listener.  Using the "pre" event, I am able to read the expired entry and update external data.

This functionality spared me from having to write my own reaper, but as far as I can tell the HotRod client implementation does not provide the same capability.  I can detect the expiration with a @ClientCacheEntryExpired, but apparently the event fires after the entry is removed from the cache and the only data available to the listener is the key.

Is there a (simple) way to duplicate the embedded behavior?  Or will I have to implement my own expiration reaper?

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the event (see [Documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/hotrod_java/hotrod_java.html#customizing_events)) to include the removed value, but the event will always be triggered after the removal.

Offtopic; the Infinispan server can communicate with a JDBC store ([Documentation)](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/server/server.html#datasources) and you can configure eviction with write-behind persistence to store your data externally (see [Eviction](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#eviction-config) and [Write-Behing](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#write_behind) documentation).